# Jquery Reverse order conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict, reverse

I'm working on a responsive website, I want to reverse the order of the 'li' (menu) when screen size and on resizing is <= 800 i tried this code but it fails randomly and sometimes when i resize to > 800 again, don't know why, maybe it's because it's conflicting with the animation for the navBar.

```
    function mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation) {
    if (allowAnimation) {
        $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            "height" : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "20px",
            "padding-bottom" : "20px",
            "height"         : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "23px",
            "padding-bottom" : "23px",
            "height"         : "60px"
        }, 200);

        $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
            "margin-top"  : "15px",
            "margin-left" : "10px"
        }, 200);
    }
}


function mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation) {

    if (allowAnimation) {

        $('#upBar, nav ul').stop(true).animate({
            "height": "45px"
        }, 200, function() {
            $('#upBar, nav ul').removeAttr("style");
        });

        $('nav ul li').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "13px",
            "padding-bottom" : "13px",
            "height"         : "45px"
        }, 200, function() {
            $('nav ul li').removeAttr('style');
        });

        $('#lang').stop(true).animate({
            "padding-top"    : "16px",
            "padding-bottom" : "16px", 
            "height"         : "45px"
        }, 200);

        $('#logo').stop(true).animate({
            "margin-top"  : "7px",
            "margin-left" : "10px"
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#logo').removeAttr('style');
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var $topNav = $('#upBar, nav'),
        allowAnimation = ($(window).width() >= 800);

    $topNav.hover(
        function(){
            mouseEnterAnimation(allowAnimation);
        },
        function() {
            mouseLeaveAnimation(allowAnimation);
        }
    );

    if (!allowAnimation) {
      $("nav ul").append($("li").get().reverse());
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        allowAnimation = ($(window).width() >= 800);

        if (allowAnimation) {

              $('nav ul').show();
        }

            else {

              $('nav ul').hide();
              $("nav ul").append($("li").get().reverse());
        }


    });

    $("#btnMobile, #menu").on("click", function(){
    $("nav ul").stop(true).slideToggle();

    });

});
```

To understand better this question i have the site on http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/news.php, don't worry about the index page, i just implemented this on the other pages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a little weird.

Once you reach you limit that is >= 800 you start doing your reverse function on resize, but we need to keep in mind that this function will be called each time the resize changes I mean once the elements are on the navbar list they will be switching again and again, so I suggest using something like a flag on the first time the reverse is made to keep track on when to reverse the elements.

Also keep in mind that you're moving with append your `<li>` elements this will cause that the `<li>` won't be anymore inside of the `<a>` and the link will become useless.

Try using something like this:

```
$("nav ul > a,  #lang").each(function(i,li){
    $("nav ul").prepend(li)
})
```

The links to the other pages will continue working after the swap.

This is just a suggestion of what I say using a flag to keep the swap state.

```
var swapped = false; 
$(window).resize(function(e) {

        allowAnimation = ($(window).width() >= 800);

        if (allowAnimation ) {

              $('nav ul').show();

        }else if(!allowAnimation && !swapped){
              swapped = true;
              $('nav ul').hide();
              $("nav ul > a,  #lang").each(function(i,li){
                  $("nav ul").prepend(li)
              })
        }

        if(swapped && allowAnimation){
           swapped = false;
           $("nav ul > a,  #lang").each(function(i,li){
                  $("nav ul").prepend(li)
              })
        }


    });
```

Other thing this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Should be :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I hope this work for you.